# Compare variables with zeta-score

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, paired-data, mean-absolute-deviation

Assume the calculation of a physical quantity $x$ from a given formula i.e. $$x=\dfrac{a*b}{c}$$ where $a, b$ and $c$ are experimental observables, therefore $x$ is a quantity derived from experimental measurements.

Now assume that there is a number $i$ of measurements, therefore there are $x_i$ quantities derived. In principle these should be in agreement, since they represent the same physical quantity. In real life, off course they deviate around a mean value.

In this scenario, it is essential to show that the $x_i$ quantities should not deviate appreciably, therefore one can calculate the $\zeta$-score using the following formula :

$$\zeta_{mn} = \dfrac{x_m-x_n}{\sqrt{\delta x_m^2 + \delta x_n^2}}$$

Here $x_m, x_n$ are the results of two experimental derivations and $\delta x_m, \delta x_n$ their corresponding uncertainties. The higher the $\zeta$-score, the more discrepant the results are.

Assume that the two calculations had a $\zeta=1$. As far as I know the result is in $\sigma$-units and to my understanding, this is a very good agreement since 1$\sigma$ implied that $x_m$ and $x_n$ agree within uncertainties.

What I would like to do, however is to translate the $\zeta$-score in a percentage i.e. what is the discrepancy of the measurements in % instead of $\sigma$ units.

My main concern is that although I am aware that a value of 1$\sigma$ corresponds to 68% in a normal distribution, an agreement within 1$\sigma$ in my point of view means a very good one and better than 68%.

So how can I properly translate the $\zeta$-score from $\sigma$ units in percentage?

Comment: Could you tell us what a "$\zeta$-score" is?  What is a "$\sigma$-unit" (presumably some kind of standard deviation or an estimate thereof) and how is it determined?  What quantity is in "agreement" with what standard value?  What would the "percentage" represent?  Perhaps a *quantile* of a distribution?

Comment: @whuber : Thank you very much for your comment! I have updated the question and I hope that it clearer!